# Where is the closure argument initialized?

Tags: closures

In this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) article about Closures

```
   function startAt(x)
       function incrementBy(y)
           return x + y
       return incrementBy

    variable closure1 = startAt(1)
    variable closure2 = startAt(5)
```

It says that *"Note that, as startAt returns a function, the variables closure1 and closure2 are of function type. Invoking closure1(3) will return 4, while invoking closure2(3) will return 8."*

Why invoking closure1(3) will return 4, and invoking closure2(3) will return 8? I cannot see where is y initialized.

Comment: `closure2` is a version of `incrementBy`, and it gets its parameter explicitly passed in, just like `incrementBy`. If you pass 3, then `y` will be bound to 3 during that call. Nothing unusual about that. (Or did you mean "where **x** is initialized"?)

Comment: But if x = 3, why 3 + y = 4? I don't get how y is initialized.

Comment: `closure2` is a method where `x` is perpetually 5, because that's the value it had when `startAt(5)` was called. That's why `x+y` evaluates to 8: `x` is 5 and `y` is 3. Thes 'freezing' of values is what closures are all about. It's weird, but you **must** wrap your head around it to grok closures.

Answer (score 1):

Your `y` variable is a formal argument of the returned  `incrementBy` function (actually a *dynamically created* closure), so it is getting its value when that function (the just built closure) is applied.

Your `x` variable (inside `incrementBy`) is a closed variable. It has to be inside the closure made inside `startAt`. That fresh closure is dynamically created at runtime, when you are calling `startAt`.

So a closure is mixing data (the values -or perhaps the references- of the closed variables) and code (much like objects do, there is a deep similarity between closures and objects) and it is generally built at runtime.

Read also about [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) since they are building closures at runtime. Read also the [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) & [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) wikipage... With anonymous functions introduced by the `fun` keyword (like in Ocaml) the example can be rewritten:

```
let startAt x =
   let incrementBy y = x + y in
   incrementBy
```

which is the same as

```
let startAt x = 
   fun y -> x + y
```

In Scheme (or Lisp) you'll use the `lambda` keyword to make anonymous function:

```
(define (startAt x) (lambda (y) (+ x y)))
```

If you are familiar or curious about Lisp, read Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book, which explains all that in great details, with implementation technicalities.

BTW, read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). It is explaining the purpose of functional values (hence what closures are) quite well.

A related (and also difficult) notion is [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).

If you are mostly a web programmer, try [HOP](http://hop.inria.fr/) or [Opa](http://opalang.org) (or perhaps [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/)). They all use nicely closures and continuations (thru [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)), notably to easily mix browser side and server side computations.